Code execution failed: Command failed: docker run --rm openjdk:11 echo '// Need to handle compilation and execution for Java separately
Error encountered:
{"success":false,"error":"Code execution failed: Command failed: docker run --rm openjdk:11 echo '// Need to handle compilation and execution for Java separately' \"import java.util.*; public class Main{ public static void main(String[] args){ System.out.println(\\\"Helloworld\\\"); }}\"\n/bin/sh: docker: not found\n"}
I have docker installed on my windows laptop still I am getting this error. many things tried like checking docker version even the docker is running.
my docker-compose.yml file
version: '3.8'

services:
  mongo_db:
    container_name: db_container
    image: mongo:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mongo_db:/data/db

  api: 
    build: .
    ports: 
      - 4000:3000
    env_file:
      - .env  # Reference your .env file
    depends_on: 
      - mongo_db
    command: npm run dev

volumes:
  mongo_db: {}

dockerFile
#### Use the official Node.js image
FROM node:alpine

#### Set the working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

#### Copy package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

#### Install dependencies
RUN npm install

#### Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

#### Expose the port
EXPOSE 4000

#### Command to run the application
CMD ["npm", "start"]


This is the node.js file where i am getting error like code execution failed it should run the command i have given but its not like that

const { exec } = require('child_process');
const util = require('util');
const execAsync = util.promisify(exec); // Promisify exec to use with async/await

/**
 * Executes the user's code inside a Docker container.
 * 
 * @param {string} code - The user's submitted code.
 * @param {string} language - The programming language (e.g., 'javascript', 'python', etc.).
 * @returns {Promise<string>} - The output of the code execution or an error message.
 */
async function executeUserCode(code, language) {
  try {
    // Map programming languages to the corresponding Docker image and command
    const dockerConfigs = {
      javascript: {
        image: 'node:16',
        cmd: 'node -e',
      },
      python: {
        image: 'python:3.9',
        cmd: 'python -c',
      },
      java: {
        image: 'openjdk:11',
        cmd: 'echo \'// Need to handle compilation and execution for Java separately\'',
        // Java would require a more complex handling because it's compiled and executed.
      },
    };

    const dockerConfig = dockerConfigs[language.toLowerCase()];

    if (!dockerConfig) {
      throw new Error(`Unsupported language: ${language}`);
    }

    // Construct the Docker command
    const dockerCommand = `docker run --rm ${dockerConfig.image} ${dockerConfig.cmd} "${code.replace(/"/g, '\\"')}"`;

    // Execute the Docker command
    const { stdout, stderr } = await execAsync(dockerCommand);

    // Check if there's any error output
    if (stderr) {
      throw new Error(`Code Error: ${stderr}`);
    }

    // Return the successful output of the code
    return stdout;
  } catch (error) {
    // If any error occurs during execution, catch it and return the error message
    throw new Error(`Code execution failed: ${error.message}`);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  executeUserCode
};



What happens if this is called with '\\"; rm -rf /; \\"' as the code parameter?  Can the caller provide a cryptocurrency miner or some sort of local kernel attack?  "Run it in Docker" really isn't sufficient protection against actually untrusted code.
